# Multiple user profiles usage in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Using Wso2 Identity Server 6.1.0

There is functionality that allows you to create multiple user profiles for a user. Is there any documentation on how to use the created profiles? Is it possible to swap context from one profile to another? If yes how to achieve it? I appreciate for any help and hints.

[image]

Tried research how to use it in documentation, but without results.
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/identity-lifecycles/customize-profiles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently WSO2 IS has the capability to create multiple profiles for a user, update the profiles, retrieve the profile etc (Mainly profile management is supported).
The public interfaces of the [userstore manager](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.9.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/common/AbstractUserStoreManager.java) component have been written in a way to manage the user based on the selected profile.

The following diagram will show how user data is accessed by different components.

[image]

Even though multiple profile support is available, the DEFAULT profile of the user is used everywhere in the main flows (for example SCIM, Oauth2) which use the user data.

eg:

- SCIM2 User listing API's service invokes `carbonUM.getUsersClaimValuesWithID` method with profile = null (which means the DEFAULT profile) as https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-inbound-provisioning-scim2/blob/315cdf390cbc249b12424dea28470a77a737b8d6/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.scim2.common/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/scim2/common/impl/SCIMUserManager.java#L4020-L4023
- The executed userstore manager method is https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/35814dfda742fcd82a92833dee0d50de38f148e7/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/common/AbstractUserStoreManager.java#L16068C47-L16069C32

---

Here is one flow where you can retrieve the user based on a claim value defined in a specific profile.
`getUniqueUserWithClaimValues(claimMap, context, profile)` this adaptive script function is supported in IS
Refer: [https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/adaptive-authentication-js-api-reference/#:~:text=getUniqueUserWithClaimValues(claimMap%2C%20context%2C%20profile)](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/adaptive-authentication-js-api-reference/#:%7E:text=getUniqueUserWithClaimValues(claimMap%2C%20context%2C%20profile))

---

Further if you have a specific usecase to retrieve a user's data defined in a specific profile, you can add an OSGi service component that invokes the userstore manager method with the relevant profile.